How to show success after a file has been downloaded?
I need to display a success message after a file has been downloaded, but my displaySuccessMessage(); runs immediately when I open a finder to download to.
Is there any way it waits for the file download to finish before running the displaySuccessMessage()?
 try {
    const jsonFile = new Blob([JSON.stringify(MyFile)], { type: 'text/plain' })

    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(jsonFile)
    link.download = 'New_File.json'
    link.click()

    link.remove()
    
    displaySuccessMessage();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

Tried putting timers, using Promises

I don't believe this is possible with just client side code.
